# why doesn't the (click)="handleEdit()" not work here

Tags: angular, primeng

Can someone tell me why the (click)=handleEdit($event) does not work?  I have bolded the html below.  It is using primeng p-button.  I have posted a similar question, but I think this one is more to the point.

```
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-10 ui-g-nopad">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <p-toolbar id="toolbarId">
                <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
                    **<button pButton type="button" label="Edit" icon="pi pi-search" id="editBtn" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="handleEdit($event)"></button>**                   
                </div>

                <div class="ui-toolbar-group-right">
                    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" id="searchId"></button>
                    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-calendar" class="ui-button-success"
                        id="calendarBtn"></button>
                    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger" id="exitBtn"></button>      
                </div>
            </p-toolbar>
        </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>



export class HomescreenComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'niche-app Home';
  appMenu: AppMenu;

  constructor(private appMenuService: AppMenuService) { }

  items: MenuItem[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appMenu = this.appMenuService.getAppMenu();
    ...
  }

  handleEdit() {
    console.log("handleEdit(): Called...");
  }

}
```

Comment: Try this instead `<p-button label="Click" (onClick)="handleClick($event)"></p-button>`

Comment: Also `import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';`

Comment: I created a junk application to just get the button to work without all the other code in my app, and it works.  I will need to dig into this more.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  The router-outlet tag needed to be moved to just beneath the p-toolbar tag.  Having it where it was caused it not to be the child of the homescreen parent component.

Once I moved the router-outlet location in the homescreen.html file, it started responding to the (click) event.

Thank you guptarahul275 for taking the time to respond to my question.

```
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-10 ui-g-nopad">
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <p-toolbar id="toolbarId">
            <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
                <button pButton type="button" label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" id="newBtn"></button>
                <button pButton type="button" label="Edit" icon="pi pi-search" id="editBtn" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="handleEdit($event)"></button>
                <button pButton type="button" label="Upload" icon="pi pi-upload" class="ui-button-success"
                    id="uploadBtn"></button>

                <i class="pi pi-bars"></i>

                <p-splitButton label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" [model]="items" styleClass="ui-button-warning"
                    id="saveBtn"></p-splitButton>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-toolbar-group-right">
                <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" id="searchId"></button>
                <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-calendar" class="ui-button-success"
                    id="calendarBtn"></button>
                <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger" id="exitBtn"></button>
            </div>
        </p-toolbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    **router-outlet used to be here**
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
   <button 
     pButton 
     type="button"
     label="Edit" 
     icon="pi pi-search"
     id="editBtn"  
     class="ui-button-danger" 
     (click)="handleEdit($event)">
      Hello
   </button>                  
</div>
```

Please copy paste the html in the page and click the button. I have tested and its printing in console

Comment: <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
                <button pButton type="button" label="Edit" icon="pi pi-search" id="editBtn" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="handleEdit($event)">Hello</button>                 
            </div>

Comment: What I found causing the problem is the <p> tag

Comment: I don't see a <p> tag.

Comment: So what I have been able to determine, is that once the router routes to a component, the parent, in the case the homescreen, does not react to the click, but if the user routes back to the home screen, it does work.  So the question is, why does the homescreen not see the click unless you are actually in homescreen component, even though the homescreen component is the parent of everything?

Comment: <p-toolbar id="toolbarId">